# jOOQ upsert a pojo

Tags: java, kotlin, jooq

Feeling a bit stupid, but I have a simple architecture where the repositories are the only ones accessing `~Record` classes and the services work on POJOs.

So basic flow is

- repository fetches into POJO
- service modifies POJO
- repository receives POJO to update DB
- repository matches updated POJO to record
- repository stores (insert or update) the record
- repository maps updated record (may have received generated values from insert) back to POJO
- service receives updated POJO

i.e. something like

```kotlin
fun save(set: MySet): MySet {
    set.description = set.description ?: ""
    val record = ctx.newRecord(MY_SET, set).apply {
        store()
    }
    // "When store() performs an INSERT statement, jOOQ attempts to load any generated keys from the database back into the record."
    // cf. https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/simple-crud/
    return record.into(MySet::class.java)
}
```

This fails because to quote documentation for `newRecord`:

> Create a new pre-filled Record that can be inserted into the corresponding table.
> This performs roughly the inverse operation of Record.into(Class)
> The resulting record will have its internal "changed" flags set to true for all values. **This means that UpdatableRecord.store() will perform an INSERT statement.** If you wish to store the record using an UPDATE statement, use executeUpdate(UpdatableRecord) instead.

I CAN, of course, check if I have an id, and then either fetch the record from the database or create a new one

```kotlin
fun save(set: MySet): MySet {
    set.description = set.description ?: ""

    val record = when (val setId = set.id) {
        null -> ctx.newRecord(MY_SET, set)
        else -> ctx.selectFrom(MY_SET).where(MY_SET.ID.eq(setId)).fetchSingle()
    }

    //TOOD: update record manually from `set`

    record.store()

    // "When store() performs an INSERT statement, jOOQ attempts to load any generated keys from the database back into the record."
    // cf. https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/simple-crud/
    return record.into(MySet::class.java)
}
```

But that kind of is a lot of boilerplate code.

I DO have access to the `MySetDao` but that one just has `insert` and `update`, there's no `store` or `upsert`, as far as I can see.

Is there a way to turn a POJO into an `UpdatableRecord` directly or is this fetch-and-manual-update the way to go?

(Worth noting: the `MySet` POJO used here was generated by jOOQ.)